# IP address wireless versus default gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-address

I'm thoroughly confused by something. I have a Windows XP computer at work that logs into a workgroup, not a domain. It has a static IP, subnet mask, and default gateway all configured under Internet Protocol (TCP/IP). By default, it cannot connect to the Internet because it doesn't have network credentials. However, I installed a wifi device so it can connect that way. If I am NOT on the network (the physical LAN cable), my IP address and tracert path look normal as I would expect when I go to a site like "What is my IP address" because it is using the wifi AND it's not on the network. However, if I AM connected to the network (the physical LAN cable), even though I'm using wifi, my IP address and tracert path change to what I would expect if I was on the company network. I don't understand why it changes. I have not provided any credentials to use the company Internet but yet it "appears" as though that's how it's connecting to the Internet even though I'm positive it's still using the wifi. Is this an optical illusion or something?

I'd like to know why it changes and how I can keep it from changing.

I can kind of get around it if I remove the default gateway, get my Internet connection, and then add the default gateway back, it'll keep the IP address that I expect, but after a while, it'll pick up the one I don't.

Any ideas? Basically, I need to be able to connect to that computer on the Network AND I want to access the Internet, but I want the IP address to look like it's accessing the wireless network, not anything via company IP addresses.

Comment: When you say "tracert path", what exactly are you talking about? Which host are you giving to `tracert`? Is it the same host in both cases? Does the "illusion" go away when you turn off Wifi?

Comment: When I type tracert google.com for example, when I have the IP address I expect and want, it goes through the servers that I would expect to see. When I have the IP address I don't want or expect, it appears to go through company servers. The tracert servers show up distinctively different for each different IP address I have. Again, I don't understand how or why because I provide no credentials for the company servers and I'm positive it's using the wifi.

Comment: **Why** are you sure it's using Wifi, when the traceroute output shows the opposite?

Comment: Because there is no way for this PC to connect to the Internet without the wifi device. As soon as I turn off the wifi device, it stops connecting to the Internet.

Comment: I think I may have fixed it. I'll have to play with it for a while longer to verify, but in the wireless device (it's a verizon mifi), there is a setting called "VPN Passthrough enable". I disabled that so it wasn't checked and my IP immediately changed from what I didn't want/expect to what I did want/expect. Hopefully that's the end of that ... we'll see.